# Which key skips to the end of code-completion insertions?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, you type an apostrophe to start a string and Idea puts the closing apostrophe there for you with the caret in the middle. You type your string.

Now to get over the last apostrophe to continue coding, I haven't found a way other than the right cursor key (or END) to move past the closing apostrophe, which are both very slow to reach on the keyboard.

Is there a built-in alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type the closing apostrophe manually that IDEA will ignore and put you outside of the string, or you can use the [SmartType completion](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Completion+features) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

Comment: Staring me right in the face - just press the character needing to be skipped over! Thanks.